# Dynamic parent and Child routes in Angular

Tags: angular-ui-router, angular6, angular-router

I have a scenario where I want the url to look like this `flavor/service` where flavor as well as service can have any value.

Based on the values selected flavor and service, I need to display data dynamically. I have to display the data on the same page irrespective of the selected flavor and service.

I have set up my routes like this:

```
{ path: ':flavor', component: DataComponent, children: [
      { path: ':service', component: DataComponent }
    ]
  }
```

It is not working, any suggestions how I can achieve this? Can I have dynamic parent as well as child??

Answer (score 0):

in angular can't make dynamic route with out static, dynamic params followed by statcic path

you can configure your routes like this

```
{ path: 'flavor/:flavor', component: DataComponent, children: [
      { path: 'service/:service', component: DataComponent }
    ]
  }
```

Here :flavor, :serive are dynamic text

you can get it form activateRoute.params

Answer (score 0):

Your Requirement can exactly be solved:

You have to use `:flavour` or `:service` in children path

Exact route config for this.

```
{ 
    path: '',
    component: DataComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: ':flavour',
        component: DataComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: ':service',
            component: DataComponent,
          }
        ]
      }
    ] 
  }
```